# Disable USB port of Android device programmatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to disable/lock the usb port of an android device programmatically?
I need to do this as my requirement is not allowed the device to connect to others using usb.
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Hi, Mari. I am also investigating connection between android device and PC via usb. The so-called USB host and USB accessory are used for connection between android device and android wear device. I find if we can disable the USB debug mode, the connection between android device and PC would be disabled, but I have no idea how to do so far. So, how about your research now?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this programmatically through any formal API. You can do it only by hacking into kernel, but that's going to be device specific.

Answer (score 0):

It's a possibility to:

Add a usb intent filter on your app.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your app intent method pick up the UsbDevice, then get its UsbDeviceConnection object and close() it.

I don't know if it works, but that's what i would try looking at the docs.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html

There are probably cleaner methods than this, but you could try it.